# git rebase. Too many conflicts in areas I would rather have master

Tags: git, rebase

My branch(B) that inherits from Master(M). Since time has passed M and B have diverged, however B only modifies an exclusive folder (f) in the tree.

The goal is to keep B in sync with M. I understand that it need to resolve conflicts in folder (f), however is there a way to simplify this such that for everything that is not f, always  use master when rebasing ?

I'm going around in circles trying to resolve conflicts for folders that I absolutely did not modify and would want to imbibe contents of M.

Tips ?

Comment: does it help to go the other way with the rebase? Or why not merge M into B, which should bring all the M changes save for f which you have as conflicts?

Comment: You should not have conflicts in files you did not change. Could it be that master was pushed with force by somebody else? Another option is that you have some untracked file outside of `f` and master creates them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the equivalent of `-s theirs` for files not in directory (folder) `f`.  Unfortunately, git doesn't have a `-s theirs` in the first place, much less one you can restrict to `f`.

All is not lost, however, and with a bit of work (shell scripting, for instance) you can automate most of this, because git *does* have `git checkout`.

While rebasing (i.e., cherry-picking commits to copy them on to the new base), whenever git stops with conflicts, you can simply `git checkout <rev> -- <path>` for any `<path>` that has a conflict.  Select the `<rev>` that corresponds to their version of the file (which, because of the way rebase reverses perspective, is simply the `HEAD` version; or you can probably use `:2:<path>` although I haven't tried this myself).  This is the equivalent of using `-s theirs` (if it existed), since it populates the index entry with their version of the file in question.  This means you don't even have to `git add` the result: it simply resolves the conflict.

Make sure you *don't* apply this to any `<path>` that lives in your directory `f`, of course.  Resolve those by hand as needed.

Once done, resume the rebase and let git do its work until you hit the next cherry-pick conflict.